# How get file contents via Filesystem Component in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, components, file-get-contents

How can i get file contents via Symfony [Filesystem component](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/filesystem.html)?

I was looked for `copy` and `mirror` methods - but they needs string as path as parameters...

In php is alternative, native function `file_get_contents()`.

Is there some method to get content via component? Or i sohould use native php function?

Or something i can't see?

Answer (score 2):

The Filesystem component provides the ability to work with files, but not their contents. With this component you can create, delete, move and do some checks of filesystem. If you want read content just use a native php functions or other components.

Comment: There is functions like ->appendToFile() which 'adds new contents at the end of some file' or ->dumpFile() to 'saves the given contents into a file' so YES this component provides the ability to work with files too...